# How to fix "markup must be well-formed" error in xml-document

Tags: xml, well-formed

I'm just starting with xml and tried to follow a tutorial. I managed to write my own xml-document, but always get this error in line 7 when I try to validate the file: "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." I tried a lot of different solutions, but nothing worked. Here's the document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <list>
        <user>
            <name>Peter</name>
            <score>7</score>
        </user> 
        <user> 
            <name>John</name>
            <score>10</score>
        </user>
    </list>
```

Sorry for my bad english, I'm not a native speaker and thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you try to validate it? What program or tool gives this message?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I use Eclipse as an IDE and try to read and write an xml-file from a java-file. It gives me the message in line 7.

Comment: Your English is excellent, and your XML as posted is actually well-formed.   See duplicate link for possible explanations and ways to fix the error, *The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed*.